# Sums and Products over sets of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, summation, products

Say I have a set of sets eg. $A:=\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\}\}$. Does this formula
$$\sum_\limits{A_i \in A}\prod_{j\in A_i}x_j$$
yield $x_1x_2+x_2x_3$?
Or does it even make sense to define a sum over a set of sets?

Comment: Yes, it's fine and you are correct.

Comment: It is not at all clear to me what your subscripted variables x_j denote, since they are never defined here. But your formula sums the products of the two members of each set A_1 and A_2, so equals 8.

Comment: @DanAsimov No, the product is over variables $x_j$ not numbers $j$. OP did not define the $x_j$ but I just assume they are some indeterminates.

Comment: Actually, as Anush points out below, the subscript should be $j \in A_i$ instead of $a \in A_i$. After that correction, it is fine.

Comment: Yes, sorry that is what was intended I will edit it.

Comment: Thank you as well!

Answer (score 1):

I assume the product in the sum was meant to be $\prod_{j\in A_i}x_j$. As long as some indexing set $I$ (possibly a set of sets) and the corresponding value for each index is something compatible with multiplication or addition then $\prod_{i\in I}$ or $\sum_{i\in I}$ respectively makes sense (a formal polynomial in this case). So even though the sum of $A_i$s themselves may not make sense, we still have $\prod_{j\in A_i}x_j$ which makes sense as $A_i$ varies over elements of $A$ which $\sum_{A_i\in A}$ sums over.